# Error: No native build was found for platform when using node pkg with serialport

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the node `pkg` package to package up my node app and create a native executable. But for some reason when I use the `serialport` npm package in my app, it compiles but when I try to run it it throws this error (no matter what platform I build for):

```
$ ./app

pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1876
      throw error;
      ^

Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=83 uv=1 libc=glibc node=14.19.2
    loaded from: /snapshot/pkg/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp

    at Function.path (/snapshot/pkg/node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js:60:9)
    at load (/snapshot/pkg/node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js:22:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/pkg/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist/load-bindings.js:10:46)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1930:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1855:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "pkg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "serialport": "^10.4.0"
  }
}
```

And here is my app.js

```
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')

const port = new SerialPort({
  path: '/dev/ttyUSB0',
  baudRate: 19200,
})

console.log('Serial port opened successfully!')
```

And this is how I build:

```
$ pkg app.js --target=node14-linux-x64
> pkg@5.7.0
```

Comment: try this pkg app.js --public --target=node14-linux-x64

Answer (score 4):

i also had this issue, add in the `package.json` the config for PKG and the important part here is the `assets` where you have to add the bindings from `serialport`, the rest you can configure them for your use.

EDIT: With the config in the package.json i run the build with `pkg . --compress Brotli`

```
"pkg": {
  "scripts": "build/**/*.js",
  "assets": [
    "node_modules/@serialport/binding*/**/*"
  ],
  "targets": [
    "node18-macos-x64",
    "node18-win-x64"
  ],
  "outputPath": "dist"
}
```